# New install desktop Ubuntu 19.04 shows error message: ucsi_ccg 0-0008: failed to reset PPM!

Tags: nvidia, 19.04

I have a brand new desktop computer on which I have installed ubuntu 19.04. When I boot the machine, I get the following error:

Jul  1 22:14:42 machinelearning kernel: [  115.801914] ucsi_ccg 0-0008: failed to reset PPM!
Jul  1 22:14:42 machinelearning kernel: [  115.803019] ucsi_ccg 0-0008: PPM init
 failed (-110)

I have managed to start SSH so I can login into the machine via ssh and do what I have to do.  However, the GUI does not come up.

Note:
I do not remember what I did to get into the GUI but whatever it was, I cannot repeat it and the GUI fails to launch.

I am checking the output of syslog and dmesg and cannot see anything obvious.

Here is my system information.
    product: Z390 M (Default string)

03/14/2019
  Z390 M-CF
  Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
video card:
GeForce GTX 1660    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 34%   39C    P0    N/A /  N/A |      0MiB /  5943MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

The problem appear to be the nvidia drivers. I have installed them based on the nvidia-smi program's suggestion.
I am on driver 418 (I am using the proprietary drivers)

Anyone any ideas?
Pranav
P.S. I also have a system log with me which is the output of  the journalctl command. I do not see a way to attach it to the question but am happy to share it.

Comment: Please run `sudo lshw | grep product | head -n1 && sudo dmidecode -s bios-release-date && sudo dmidecode -s baseboard-product-name && sudo dmidecode -s baseboard-manufacturer` and paste the result into your question after clicking [edit]. Also please put two space characters after each end of line before you press Enter so what you post formats well. Please do not click on Add Comment as new comments shove old comments off screen; your information about your PC and installation should all go in the Question.

Comment: `startx` is the traditional command to restart a GUI from the command line.

Comment: FWIW, my system (with the same GPU) reports "failed to reset PPM" too. This doesn't prevent it from booting though, only resuming from sleep. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1850238 for more information.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same entries in my log. also my computer had a 50 second hang after resuming from suspend during which desktop is black.
`ucsi_ccg` is a modprobe module for `nvidia` gpu `type-c` controller.
as described [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1850238) this problem appeared in kernel `5.3.x+`.
as workaround you can disable this module by creating `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-usb.conf` with the `blacklist ucsi_ccg` string and rebooting your computer.

**Note:**
Blacklisting of this module disables the usb-c connector on the video card.

Comment: I am using `nouveau` drivers, so should I as well blacklist `ucsi_ccg` . 
I am seeing this: ```[     7.017666] nvidia-gpu 0000:02:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[    7.017677] ucsi_ccg 1-0008: i2c_transfer failed -110
[    7.017678] ucsi_ccg 1-0008: ucsi_ccg_init failed - -110
```

Comment: Blacklisting might then result in not being able to use the USB-C connector for video output, right? :)

Comment: @stephanmg, yes, of course, blacklisting of this module disables the usb-c connector on the video card. I thought it was self-evident. apparently worth adding this to my answer. thank you

Comment: What I mean is, if I see this problem it is because I do not use the NVIDIA proprietary driver? Does `nouveau` driver allow me to use the USB-C connector for a second monitor I want to use with the same VGA as for the first monitor?

Comment: @stephanmg, oh, I do not know exactly about that. I do not use this port at all. blacklisting of this port is intended to disable it and prevent syslog error messages and reduce the time the computer wakes from standby. but [this article](https://www.eurogamer.net/articles/digitalfoundry-2019-02-28-psa-the-usb-c-port-on-rtx-graphics-cards-isnt-just-for-vr) says that usb-c port can indeed be used to connect a monitor. and I think that the proprietary driver is more usable for this. but it is not exactly. only imao

Comment: @stephanmg, [this guy](https://www.linux.org/threads/direct-usb-c-connection-to-external-monitor-not-working.30253/) uses a usb-c port for a portable monitor and he uses a proprietary driver. I don't know if the nouveau driver works with this port, but the proprietary one obviously does.

Comment: Looks like NVIDIA GTX 1660 TI has a "fake USB-C controller", so it should not be possible. That's probably the reason why you also want to blacklist the module!

Comment: Just quick follow up with you. I totally missed that I simply can connect to the HDMI and DP two monitors. The card has no support for USB-C, but HDMI, DP and DVI-D, so I attached three (working) monitors directly to the NVIDIA GPU card. :)