# Possible to use multiple ports on Dell XPS 8940 for NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti output to multiple (four) monitors?

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, multiple-monitors

My Dell XPS 8940 has a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti with the following three connectors:

1. DisplayPort
2. HDMI
3. DVI-D

Currently I am attaching one monitor to the HDMI port.

**Question:** Is there any chance how I can get two monitors working in Ubuntu 20.04 by attaching to DisplayPort or DVI-D another monitor?

**Bonus question:** The mainboard seems to have an USB-C connector, can this USB-C connector be used also for attaching an additional monitor to the computer?

Per this thread ([New install desktop Ubuntu 19.04 shows error message: ucsi_ccg 0-0008: failed to reset PPM!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1155263/new-install-desktop-ubuntu-19-04-shows-error-message-ucsi-ccg-0-0008-failed-to)) the USB-C connector seems to be causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

(Answering my own question, mainly for future references and might hope that could help somebody else too)

Looks like the three connectors work to attach three monitors.

However the NVIDIA Geforce GTX 1660 Ti has a "fake" USB-C controller which I can't load:

```
[    6.861728] nvidia-gpu 0000:02:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[    6.861738] ucsi_ccg 0-0008: i2c_transfer failed -110
[    6.861742] ucsi_ccg 0-0008: ucsi_ccg_init failed - -110
```

This is independent on the usage of either the `nouveau` driver or proprietary NVIDIA driver (460 tested proprietary) provided on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.

DVI-D, HDMI and DP can be driven simultaneously with Xorg.

(Depending on your mainboard and CPU combination you might have an additional DP and HDMI output which is attached to the integrated GPU, in my case Intel UHD 630)

Stephan